# Saving the data of a table view in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, userdefaults

I'm trying to build a simple to-do list app with Swift 3 and Xcode 8. It includes a text input box, a submit button, and a table, where each cell includes a title and a subtitle that shows the date. So far, all of this has worked.

Currently, I'm trying to get it to save when I leave the app. I've tried user defaults (which I have succesfully used in the past, but wasn't working for this), core data (which seemed like a lot of excess code, will do if I have to), and a JSON file I tried to read and write from with SwiftyJSON (have also succesfully used this). None of these have worked.

What would be the simplest/best way to solve my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Choose one from SQLite Db or CoreData & that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to persist data locally in those circumstances is probably to use [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding). See the "Persist Data" section in Apple's [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html) guide.

You might also want to take a look at Apple's sample code [Lister (for watchOS, iOS, and OS X)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Lister), which demonstrates a productivity app for iOS and OS X that enables you to create and share to-do lists across devices. A user can store their documents both locally or in iCloud, but this may be more than you need for your use case.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data into: userdefaults, files in documents folder, coredata, SQLite db, third-party like realm. You can send also to your remote server.